# Recoger datos de inputs y enviarlos a la base de datos

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Necesito obtener los datos de varios input y guardarlos en una base de datos de Mongodb con express y Nodejs, el error es un cannot get, estoy usando plantillas ejs

Codigo html

```
   <form action="/save-profile/<%= user.id %>/<%= user.name %>/<%= user.apellido %>/<%= user.description %>" method="POST">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Nombre</span><%= user.username %>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="'John'" aria-label="Username" name="username">
            <span class="input-group-text">Apellidos</span><%= user.apellido %>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="example: 'Smith'" aria-label="Server" name="apellido">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-text">Descripcion:</span>
            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder="Pequeña descripcion sobre ti" name="description"><%= user.description %></textarea>
        </div>
        </p><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-10 btn-lg" onclick="savePerfil()">Guardar</button>
```

Codigo Js

```
router.post('/save-profile/:id/:username/:apellido/:description', async (req, res) => {
var data = {
    "save-profile": {
        "id": req.params.id,
        "username": req.params.username,
        "apellido": req.params.apellido,
        "description": req.params.description
    }
};
const updatedProfile = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(data)

console.log(updatedProfile)
res.redirect('/profile')})
```

Comment: El método `http` por defecto para un botón tipo `submit` es `POST`. Por otro lado, ¿a qué `url` estás haciendo la petición y cómo? El código que muestras es insuficiente para determinar con certeza el problema. Saludos

Comment: la url es /save-profile/ y luego paso los valores por url

Comment: Cambie a router.post y sigue igual no puedo recibir los datos